# Check whether specific attribute is available on parent element

Tags: javascript

I have a button like this

```
<button data-cart-itemid="1be8718a-6993-4036-b7c6-8579e342675d" data-action="inc">
```

When I click on the document I need to check whether it clicked on that button. I need to check it using the attribute `data-action="inc"`

I tried this code, but it always gives me false

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    console.log(e.target.closest('button').hasAttribute("[data-action='inc']"));
});
```

Comment: I don't get it... with this code `e.target` is already the button when you click it. You don't need to do all this closes.hasAttribute thing

Comment: @Arnau, if the user clicked on the icon of the button, it is recognized as another e.target. So I get the parent.

Comment: Then check this, maybe it's useful for your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Answer (score 0):

To expand my last comment, you could do something like this

```
<body>
<button data-cart-itemid="1be8718a-6993-4036-b7c6-8579e342675d" data-action="inc">
  <img src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/themes/fx/assets/img/footer/footer-roket.png">click it</span>
  </button>
</body>


document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.target.activeElement)
});
```

https://jsbin.com/yifulebate/edit?html,js,console,output